# WordPress Update Post Meta When User Clicks on Hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to update a post meta key when a user clicks on a link from the front end of a WordPress blog. What I really want is for the dealexp_expired_status key to update to value 'on' when the user clicks on the link.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here is the code I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
$content = dealexp_add_exp_link() . $content;

// Returns the content.
return $content;
}

function dealexp_add_exp_link() {
$exp_url = plugins_url('/deal-expirator/includes/update.php');
?>
<a href="<?php echo $exp_url; ?>?update_key=1">Mark Expired</a>
<?php }
```

And in the update.php file, I have:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["update_key"])) {
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealexp_expired_status', 'on');
}

?>
```

However, I am getting a fatal error when clicking on the link. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create hyperlink with new parametr. For example index.php?update_key=1
2. In needed php file create php block.

For example if you are doing it in single.php then paste such code inside `while ( have_posts() )` block:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["update_key"])) {update_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealexp_expired_status', 'key_value');} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to use it with the WordPress content filter though, and need each link to update each individual post. To clarify, I'm trying to create a plugin using this.

Comment: I have just updated the original post to include the code I have right now. Can you take a look and see what I am doing wrong that would produce a fatal error? Thanks!